# How to create a proxy class to lowercase the keys in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some old code that involves Pandas and Json. The old Json used to use proper-casing like so:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Bob"
    }
]
```

The new json uses lower case like so:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "Bob"
    }
]
```

There are thousands of lines of tested and formerly-working Python code that assumed the proper casing like so:

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_json(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
print(df['FirstName'])
```

(The actual Python code is more complex.  A small number of Pandas data frame functions are called such as `to_dict`, `sort_values`, `drop_duplicates`)

The above code fails.  This code works:

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_json(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
print(df['firstname'])
```

I have to go around to all the code and lowercase everything.  While that would be a good maintenance task (and I do agree it should be done)  What I need to do is rapidly overcome this trivial issue for now.  I want to rig this so that the Data Frame will accept a case-insensitive key.

What I attempted to do was create a decorator class, then a proxy class and a few other ideas to see if I can intercept the key before it hits the Pandas DataFrame and lowercase the key.  So far, my efforts have failed.  Here is one idea I tried:

```
class lowercaseproxy:
    def __init__(self, proxied_object):
        self.__proxied = proxied_object

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return __proxied.__getattribute__(key.lower())

import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_json(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
df = lowercaseproxy(pd.DataFrame(f))
print(df['FirstName'])
```

I think I'm looking for something along the lines of the proxy class idea.  The solution should:

- lowercase all the keys
- allow built-in Pandas function to still work such as: `to_dict`, `sort_values`, `drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicate that only a small number of methods are called, you could define a class that inherits from [pandas.Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and override each of said methods.

For instance:

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import Any


class lowercaseproxy(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args)

    def __getitem__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        return super().__getitem__(__name.lower())

    def sort_values(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if args:
            return super().sort_values(args[0].lower(), *args[1:], **kwargs)
        kwargs["by"] = kwargs["by"].lower()
        return super().sort_values(*args, **kwargs)
```

So that with the following toy dataframe:

```
df = lowercaseproxy(
    {
        "firstname": ["Bob", "Mack", "John"],
    }
)
```

This works:

```py
print(df["FirstName"])
# Output
0     Bob
1    Mack
2    John
Name: firstname, dtype: object
```

And so do those method calls:

```py
# positional argument
print(df.sort_values("FirstName"))
# Output
  firstname
0       Bob
2      John
1      Mack

# keyword argument
print(df.sort_values(by="FirstName"))
# Output
  firstname
0       Bob
2      John
1      Mack
```